# Output current session log to log window and file

Tags: sas

Is there a way to get Base Sas 9.3 to print the current session log to the log window AND a log file? I can use the printto procedure to switch, but as far as I can tell it will only do one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

You could always use `proc printto` to send it to a file, turn off Proc Printto, and then read it in and output it.  This actually gets you log highlighting, which is nice.

```
filename a temp;
proc printto log=a;
run;
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
run;
proc printto;
run;

data _null_;
infile a;
input @;
put _infile_;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option: ALTLOG.  This is *only* valid on system startup (either appended to the SAS executable text in your shortcut, or placed in your config file), so it's not very flexible; but it allows your log to go to a file AND the screen.  So if your shortcut is

```
c:\pathtosas\sas.exe -config "myconfigfiledetails"
```

You can append

```
c:\pathtosas\sas.exe -config "myconfigfiledetails" -altlog "c:\temp\seemylog.txt"
```

(of course replace the dummy text with correct text).